# Using JQuery mobile to create apps

Tags: visual-studio, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have tried to create simple apps for android. For this I used Eclipse.

I want to find out what there is out there (Good frameworks) for building platform independent apps. I fell over JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap/Apache Cordova (and some other frameworks).

What I was not able to find out, is what editor are used with JQuery Mobile. Am I wrong thinking that anything can be used, since it is just Javascript and css3? Can one use Visual studio for this?

I also read that JQuery mobile can be used with PhoneGap, with out further explanation. What does this mean exactly? Why would you use JQuery with PhoneGap, instead of using pure phoneGaP?
So to recap the questions

1. Can JQuery mobile be used with Visual Studio? If not, what editors do you suggest?
2. What does it mean that JQuery mobile can be used with PhoneGaP? I thought these 2 were separate frameworks?

Answer (score 2):

```
1.Can JQuery mobile be used with Visual Studio? If not, what editors do you suggest?
```

You can use any UI framework ( Jquery Mobile, Sencha touch, Dojo toolit, Kendo UI, Ionic, ..etc) as all the frameworks are based on Javascript, HTML5 and CSS3.
As such you can choose any editors which you are comfortable with.
Some popular editors to name a few **WebStorm, Sublime Text, Eclipse, Visual Studio.**

```
2. What does it mean that JQuery mobile can be used with PhoneGaP? I thought these 2 were separate frameworks?
```

JQuery is a HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript framework.
PhoneGap is a Webview Framework.
PHoneGap allows you to use **ANY** HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript framework ( UI frameworks mentioned above) OR you could just use **plain** HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript **without ANY** framework to build apps and then wrap it in PhoneGap.
Using PhoneGap you can have access to **DEVICE APIs** (like Device contact list, Acceloremeter, Camera etc), which otherwise would not have been possible using only HTML5, CSS and JS.

Comment: This means that if I use pure JQuery mobile framework, then I can not have access to the device APIs? For this I will need to wrap it in PhoneGap/Cordova?

Comment: If you just create a web App using pure JQuery Mobile Framwork without using PhoneGap/cordova you can access the Web App via the Mobile Browser, But it will not have access to device APIs. Wrapping it with PhoneGap/Cordova allows you to access DEVICE APIs.