# Creating apps for several platforms with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I heard that PhoneGap can be used to develope platformindependent apps, and that different IDEs could be used. But when I search, all the examples use eclipse, and are for android.

Question1: Was I wrong thinking that you would just create one app with phonegap, and this app would work on different platforms?

Question2: Can one use VS with PhoneGap?

Question3: Why would one use JQuery MB framework with phonegap, instead of just going pure phonegap? After all, phonegap also allows html5, css3 and JS/JQuery.

On the installation guide, one of the steps say
- phonegap run android  (Take from: http://phonegap.com/install/)

Question4: Again, I am thinking... Are you bound to use Eclipse?

Question5: Can C# be used as code-behind, instead of Java?

Comment: Have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367698/using-jquery-mobile-to-create-apps/25369143#25369143) about JQuery MB and phoneGap.

Answer (score 1):

1. you were not wrong.
2. yes, you can.
3. jq mobile is UI framework, phonegap is 'backend' bridge between native functionalities and webview (btw. jq mobile is very sluggish with phonegap, you should get familiar with ionic for example, or many other ui frameworks).
4. youre not bound to eclipse, Im using intellij for example.
5. there is very little 'code-behind', if you dont intend to write plugins, then its like 5 lines of native code, rest is JAVASCRIPT. If you develop for android you have to use java as backend code, for iOS its objective-c, windows phone.. I dont know.

Comment: By backend I think he meant SERVER side code (code hosted on the WebServer)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
I am gonna have much code-behind, as I am gonna use a database to save data, and make calls to retrieve data. I guess this will happend with AJAX or JSON. So I guess I am not bound to use Java, like ALL the examples do (The examples I found so far)

Comment: Yes I meant server. Sorry for the missing clerification

Comment: you are wrong. all code regarding to database will also be written in javascript or even will be handled by server. you will just have bunch of ajax requests in your app to communicate with some server (in PHP for example) and send something like www.mydomain.com/actions/register?u=user&p=pw and all the logic of registering will be on server side. you will just return JSON saying "{status: ok}" and handle that somehow

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, about the AJAX requests. Then I guess this answers my question about whether we can use C# as server side code. It must be possible to do this, where the C# code just returns a boolean, that then is read by the AJAX code. Isn't this true.

I didn't know however, that the use/call to the device API is done in client code.

Comment: @user1960836 You can use any technology at the backend(server) i.e JAVA, JSP, ASP, .NET, C#, PHP, JAVAScript as long as these technologies return a response(data) that is understood by the client. The response data can be XML, SOAP, JSON, HTML, CSV as long as the client is able to deal with it.